# Export JQuery Drag and Drop to image

Tags: php, jquery

I created a simple drag and drop, but my real aim here is to save/export/download the final result as image/jpg/png
How is this possible?

Drawing.php

```
 <div id="picture1">
         <img src="images/icon1.png">
     </div>
     <div id="picture2">
         <img src="images/icon2.png">
     </div>
     <div id="dropme">
         <img src="images/plan1.jpg">
     </div>
     <style>
         #dropme{
             height: auto;
         }
         #dropme img{
             width:80%;
             max-width: 100%;
         }
         #picture1{  
             width: 159px;
             height: 80px;
        }   
        #picture2{   
             width: 80px;
             height: 79px;
        }    
         </style>
          </div>
           </div>
```

java.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#picture1, #picture2').draggable({
        containment:'document'});
    $('#dropme').droppable({
        drop:function(){

    }});
});
```

So, all i want to know is how i can export the final result into an image